# Spring-Cloud-Contract dynamically returning boolean from request in body of response

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am writing out spring-cloud-contracts using the `YAML DSL` and ran into the following issue.

I am trying to dynamically return a boolean from a request in the body of my response. When I set the body to be the boolean from the request, the response is returning the boolean as a string instead of as a bool. Is there a way I can dynamically return a boolean value to get my desired response in the example below?

#### Example Contract:

```
name: POST foo
request:
  method: POST
  urlPath: /foo
  body:
    myBool: true
  matchers:
    body:
      - path: $.myBool
        type: by_regex
        predefined: any_boolean
response:
  status: 201
  body:
    myBool: "{{{ jsonpath this '$.myBool' }}}"
```

#### Desired Response:

```
{
  myBool: true
}
```

#### Actual Response

```
{
  myBool: "true"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/project-features.html#yaml) you can provide a type using `regexType` as follows

```
- path: $.thing1
  type: by_regex
  value: thing2
  regexType: as_string
```

so in your case just provide `regexType: as_boolean`

Comment: I have not been able to get that to work. Am I missing something? The documentation is not very clear. I get the exact same behavior.

I added the following to the response:
```
  matchers:
    body:
      - path: $.myBool
        type: by_regex
        predefined: any_boolean 
        regexType: as_boolean
```
Edit: didn't realize you could not add code blocks to comments

Comment: What exactly isn't clear? You have exactly the same thing as you want byt the regex type is different and I've copied what you should do

Comment: Adding that matcher did not work.
I need to cast a value as a bool using the code explained here:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-dsl-referencing-request-from-response

Comment: Please create a sample that replicates the problem and file an issue

Comment: Here is a gist with more details. I hope this is more clear, it includes the suggestion you gave me. However, I am not certain I implemented it in the way your intended.
https://gist.github.com/JosephGaiser/08190da6de7fc43cdf0b41ea8de690d3

Comment: If you feel that this is a bug let me know and I will file an issue. I think that I am just doing something wrong though. Take a look at that gist I posted above and let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You have written this someBool: "{{{ jsonpath this '$.someBool' }}}", what if you remove the brackets?

Comment: Have you read this?  

{{{ jsonpath this 'your.json.path' }}}: Returns the element from the request that matches the JSON Path. For example, for a JSON path of $.here, use {{{ jsonpath this '$.here' }}}

You need the brackets... Is there someone else who could help with this? It seems you are not familiar with yaml dsl

Comment: Thanks @Joseph for your kind reply, I am the author of this library and that DSL (but maybe as you say I'm not familliar with YAML DSL). Good luck on fixing this with somebody else. Bye!

Comment: I appreciate your time Marcin. I will update this post if I manage to find a solution.